# Grails Criteria dynamic AND conditions for one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, dynamic, grails-orm, one-to-many, criteria

I have a domain class

```
class Url {
        UUID id
        String url
        static hasMany = [            
            indications:UrlIndication
        ]
        ...
}
```

And

```
class UrlIndication  {
    UUID id
    String name

    static belongsTo =  Url
   ...

}
```

I want to choose urls so that it has all the necessary `UrlIndication` elements in a given list `indicationsId`.
For that I use an association `and` criteria like this one:

```
indications {
                and {
                        indicationsId.each{
                            indication->
                                eq ('id',UUID.fromString(indication as String))
                        }
                    }
            }
```

However, all I got is an empty result. Can you suggest any modifications/ other methods so that I can do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returned an empty list because it's the equivalent of the expression (pseudo-code): `if 1 = 1 and 1 = 2 and 1 = 3`

Such an expression would always be false. `in` or `inList` would not work for the reason @innovatism described.

In theory, Criteria's `eqAll()` or HQL's `= ALL` would work. *But*, I don't know for sure because I could not get either one to work.

What will work is to use `inList` to return a subset of `Urls`: those which contain at least one of the `UrlIndication` IDs. Then use Groovy's `containsAll()` to finish the job.

```
def ids = indicationsId.collect { UUID.fromString(it as String) }

Url.createCriteria()
    .buildCriteria {
        indications {
            inList 'id', ids
        }
    } 
    .setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .list()
    .findAll {
        it.indications.id.containsAll(ids)
    }
```

Since the query has the potential to return duplicate `Url` instances, the `ResultTransformer` is set to return a unique list.

Finally, `findAll()` is used along with `containsAll()` to filter the list further.

## Using eqAll (maybe)

Something like the following might work. Something funky is going on with Grails' HibernateCriteriaBuilder that causes the eqAll method to look up properties in the root entity; completely ignoring the sub criteria. So the following uses Hibernate directly. It didn't work for me, but it's as close as I could get. And it gave me a head-ache!

```
Url.createCriteria().buildCriteria {}
    .createCriteria('indications', 'i')
    .add(org.hibernate.criterion.Property.forName('i.id').eqAll(org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria.forClass(UrlIndication)
        .add(org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions.in('id', ids))
        .setProjection(org.hibernate.criterion.Property.forName('id'))
    ))
    .setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .list()
```

The problem I had is I could not get `Restrictions.in` to work. `Restrictions.eq` works fine.

Comment: FInally, I had the same approach, but that bothered me when I want to use paginate. Do you have any suggestions about that?Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realized _you're_ innovatism. LOL! Anyway, You won't be able to use GORM pagination with this method because the offset/max values become useless when you filter the list down after getting the results from GORM. You'd have to paginate the final list. I'm not sure if such an implementation already exists. I updates my answer with something that might work, if you've got some keyboard grease left.

Comment: @innovatism, a new question similar to this one came up recently. There's an HQL query that might work for you. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856121/grails-how-to-best-construct-a-hibernate-criteria-builder-to-search-hasmany

Answer (score 0):

the `in` clause should do:

```
indications {
     'in' 'id', indicationsId.collect{ UUID.fromString indication.toString() }
}
```

Comment: This will give you urls having either of the elements or both, and not urls that have ALL of these element.