# Grails hasmany search for exact items of hasmany

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I have two GORM domain classes. One is a card and the card has many purchases on it. is there any way i can search for cards that have greater than or equal to of certain purchases. Here might be an example

We have 4 cards:

Card1: orange, orange, apple
Card2: apple, orange
Card3: orange, orange
Card4: apple, apple, orange

Lets say i wanted to search for all cards that have 2 or more oranges. so that would only return cards 1,3. Having the search based off of the purchases name.

Comment: You can do that with subqueries, see `DetachedCriteria` in documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your domain classes are something like this...

```
class Card {
    static hasMany = [purchases: Purchase]
}

class Purchase {
    String name
}
```

Here's how you can do it:

```
def cards = Card.withCriteria {
    resultTransformer = org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY 

    sizeGe('purchases', 2)

    purchases {
        eq('name', 'orange')
    }
}
```

Instead of using a subquery, you can use `sizeGe()` which counts the number of items in a *collection* and looks for a count greater than or equal to the number provided.

However, adding `eq()` to the query causes the result to contain duplicates due to grouping. A side-effect a sub-query would not have. So the `DISTICT_ROOT_ENTITY` result transformer filters out the duplicates **after the fact**.

You can learn more about criteria queries from my articles [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/).

Comment: Actually this looks like it is requiring only one of the purchases to be orange. Is there a way i can say at least two of them are orange?

Comment: Yeah... that's a far more complicated problem. I've answered that question a number of times. I think this is the best solution I have found thus far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856121/grails-how-to-best-construct-a-hibernate-criteria-builder-to-search-hasmany/32872048#32872048

Comment: Awesome. That worked for getting multiple of the same purchases but i still have one problem. I'm trying to use executeQuery twice then finding the intersection of the two sets so users can specify multiple purchases but when i try to do executeQuery twice it returns the first search when i try it a second time. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Groovy does have intersection capabilities, so it's possible to get what you're looking for. Get with me on Grails Noob and we'll figure it out together: http://emmanuelrosa.com

Comment: I solved it. I made the first search then called search.intersect(second_search) without assigning it to the search. Thanks for all the help